# Bash script for beeping the number of hours not working

Tags: bash, shell-script

The script beeps the number of hours. That is, if you run the script at 10'o Clock, it'll beep 10 times.
Further, after a pause of 3 seconds, I have to make it beep once if the minute lies between 15-30, twice if it lies between 30-45, and thrice if it lies between 45-60.
No beeps are to be there for the first 15 minutes.
This is what I have come up with till now:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%I)
count=0
while test $count -lt $time; do
echo -e "\a"
sleep 1 # sleep for one second
let count=count+1
done
sleep 3
minute=$(date +%M)
if test $minute -gt 15 && $minute -lt 30; then
echo -e "\a"
elif test $minute -gt 30 && $minute -lt 45; then
echo -e "\a"
echo -e "\a"
elif test $minute -gt 45 && $minute -lt 60; then
echo -e "\a"
echo -e "\a"
echo -e "\a"
else echo "No Chime"
fi
```

The first part of the code works fine. For example, if the time is 11:25, it beeps for 11 times and pauses for 3 seconds. But after that, it shows no chime

```
line 11: 25: command not found
line 13: 25: command not found
```

I have checked on shellcheck as well, and it returns no error. Yet, the code doesn't seem to work.

How do i make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you ignore indentation?

Comment: You are missing a `then` after your last `elif`

Comment: What steeldriver said. just add a `then` the sqme as for the other elif: `elif test $minute -gt 45 && $minute -lt 60; then`.

Comment: For the future, you may want to bookmark [www.shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the syntax error. However, the command still doesn't work. I have posted an edit.

Comment: @terdon sir, the question has been put on hold, and now I am unable to seek answers for it. And I have a fast approaching deadline.

Comment: Well, that's a different question. In general, you should ask new questions as, well, a new question. But since nobody had answered the original one, we can reopen.

Comment: `test` doesn't chain like that: `test $minute -gt 15 && $minute -lt 30` - it needs to be separate commands `test $minute -gt 15 && test $minute -lt 30` (or the equivalent using `[ . . .]` or `[[ . . . ]]` brackets

Comment: @terdon i understand the level of experts we have over here. These have been my first few hours on this site. And I have been banned from asking further questions for 7 days. I am new to linux. Completely. And I have been trying to research as much as i can about it.

Comment: @steeldriver I will try to run it now. Thank you for correcting me. I found this example somewhere, and used it the way it was. I shall be back in a minute.

Comment: @steeldriver it seemed to have worked. I need to wait for 15 minutes to find out if it chimes. Strange though that shellcheck did not pick up the error. But thank you! You've been of grate help :)

Comment: @ShivangChaturvedi you've been banned automatically by the system because your question was downvoted. Nothing we can do about that, I'm afraid. To avoid this next time, make sure you show that you have tried to solve it yourself. Simply dumping 20 lines of code and asking "how do I make it work" will not be a popular question here. You could at least show that you read the error and realize there was a problem in line 21, and show what you tried to change to fix it. We're all volunteers here and we expect people asking questions to put in a little effort.

Comment: @terdon I am in my early twenties, probably the amount of experience you hold in linux. The codes you feel I have "Dumped" are the ones I have come up with after investing 6+ hours, apart from my other commitments. I am not looking for "popularity" but guidance, which unfortunately, has been coming in a hostile manner to be honest. And the fact that even after the first edit an error existed, on shellcheck as well, goes to show that it is easier said than done when it comes to checking codes. This question would've never had 20 lines of codes if there was no "effort" in the first place. :)

Comment: @ShivangChaturvedi I meant effort in asking. Your two questions so far ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/362972/1), and this one) have simply been i) what looks like a homework requirement, without any evidence of your having tried anything at all. It looked like you just copy/pasted ther text of your assignment. You weren't even asking for help! You were giving commands: "write a script". That is rude and shows a total lack of effort. ii) This one just showed the script and a clear error message which you didn't even mention. You didn't seem to have tried fixing it at all.

Comment: New and inexperienced users are welcome here, but lack of knowledge is no reason to write a sloppy question. Ignorance is not against the rules here, but we do dislike lazy questions. You might have spent hours trying to fix it but if you don't show any of your work, we have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
elif test $minute -gt 30 && $minute -lt 45; then
```

The `test` builtin is a command. So the line above is running `command1 && command2`. However, you don't have `test` after the `&&` so it tries to run `$minute` as a command and fails. You meant to write:

```
elif test $minute -gt 30 && test $minute -lt 45; then
```

Same for the next one:

```
elif test $minute -gt 45 && test $minute -lt 60; then
```

That said, you should really get into the habit of indenting your code. It helps readability enormously and any decent editor will do it for you. Also, note that your script won't work if the minute is exactly `30` or `45` since you're using `-lt` (less than) instead of `-le` (less than or equal) So, a better version of your script would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%I)
count=0
while [ "$count" -lt "$time" ]; do
        echo -ne "\a"
        sleep 1 # sleep for one second
        let count=count+1
done
sleep 3
minute=$(date +%M)
if [[ $minute -gt 15 && $minute -le 30 ]]; then
     echo -ne "\a"
elif [[ $minute -gt 30 && $minute -le 45 ]]; then
        echo -ne "\a\a"
elif [[ $minute -gt 45 && $minute -lt 60 ]]; then
        echo -ne '\a\a\a'
else
        echo "No Chime"
fi
```

Of course, because you are sleeping for so many seconds, the time the beeps represent is not the time you started the script at (for instance, if run at 11:59:50, you'll issue 11 beeps; by that time, the hour will be `12:00:01` and you won't issue any more beeps letting the listener think the time is between `11:00` and `11:15`). Are you sure you don't want to set `time` and `minute` at the very beginning of the script so that it beeps the right time at you? I didn't change that since I don't know what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @terdon. The codes seems to work now. Thank you for showing the correct way of getting the multiple chimes as well. However, in line 16, do I use single quotes, double quotes, or doesn't matter? Also, for putting time and minute right up there, I am not sure about how it is done for real. But I am supposed to give a 3 seconds pause before the chime can run according to the minutes.

Comment: Both types of quotes work here. Double quotes will also expand any variables in the string but for what you are doing, single quotes are fine.

Comment: See also `printf '\a'` for a simpler and more portable way to write a BEL character.

Comment: While you're at using ksh-style `[[...]]` operators, you might as well use the more readable `((minute > 45 && minute < 60))` (btw, minute will always be less than 60). Also, you may want to use another shell than `bash` as `bash` will complain when `$minute` is `09`. Or go back to using the standard `test`/`[` command.

Comment: Stricktly speaking, it should be `sleep 2` for the minute beeps to be issued 3 seconds after the last hour beep.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas strictly speaking, there are really too many issues with even the idea of the script, let alone its implementation. I am assuming this is just a silly homework assignment chosen only to get the students to practice scripting.

Comment: A good reason to teach rigour and point out pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` specifically, you can do:

```
#! /bin/bash -
printf -v code '%(
   h_chimes=%-I m_chimes=$((%-M/15))
)T' -1
eval "$code"

nbeep() for ((i = 0; i < $1; i++)) {
  ((i == 0)) || sleep 1
  printf '\a'
}

nbeep "$h_chimes"
if ((m_chimes > 0)); then
  sleep 3
  nbeep "$m_chimes"
fi
```